# In C++ Is there anyway to call an object attribute through a string?

Tags: c++

Say I have an object defined like this:

```
struct Something
{
    int attribute1;
    string attribute2;
}
```

I then have a File that contains a bunch of information that should be applied to a created object. However, the attribute name that it should be applied to is also stored in the file. In other words, the text file would contain two values like so:

```
123, "attribute1"
```

I need a way to reference an object's attribute by a string. Something like `Something[variable_holding_attribute_name]` would be perfect!

Is there any way of doing this in C++? Please also note that I can't use a `map`, as the object contains more than 1 data type.

Comment: No native support for reflection in C++ as of today.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your requirement, but wouldn't something like [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/any.html) help?

Comment: You can create a `std::map<std::string, functor>` (or similar) to look up a bit of code to set a field associated with a particular name. You do need to build and maintain the map manually though.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Since each is so customized, might as well make it a template function: `template<class membertype, class classtype> membertype& get_mem_by_name(classtype* parent, const char* name);` and allow it to be specialized/overloaded.

Comment: You can use a map. The map would map a name to something that takes a string.

Comment: Is the file format already fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Just because your `struct` uses different data types does not mean you cannot use a `std::map` to access them, because you can. Try something like this:

```
struct Something
{
    int attribute1;
    std::string attribute2;
};

void set_attr1(Something &obj, const std::string &value)
{
    std::istringstream iss(value);
    iss >> obj.attribute1;
}

void set_attr2(Something &obj, const std::string &value)
{
    obj.attribute2 = value;
};
```

```
typedef void (*set_func)(Something&, const std::string&);

std::map<std::string, set_func> m;
m["attribute1"] = &set_attr1;
m["attribute2"] = &set_attr2;

...

Something obj;

std::string value = ...; // "123"
std::string name = ...; // "attribute1"

m[name](obj, value);
/*
Or safer:
std::map<std::string, set_func>::iterator iter = m.find(name);
if (iter != m.end())
    iter->second(obj, value);
*/
```

If you want something a little more flexible that allows you to re-use a given function for multiple fields of the same data type, even re-use the same functions for `map`s of different `struct`s, you can do this instead:

```
template<typename ObjType, typename MemType, MemType ObjType::*member>
void set_member(ObjType &obj, const std::string &value)
{
    std::istringstream iss(value);
    iss >> obj.*member;
}

template<typename ObjType, std::string ObjType::*member>
void set_str_member(ObjType &obj, const std::string &value)
{
    obj.*member = value;
}

template<typename ObjType>
struct set_member_hlpr
{
    typedef void (*func_type)(ObjType&, const std::string&);
};
```

```
struct Something
{
    int attribute1;
    std::string attribute2;
};

std::map<std::string, set_func_hlpr<Something>::func_type > m;
m["attribute1"] = &set_member<Something, int, &Something::attribute1>
// you can use set_member() for Something::attribute2, but
// std::istringstream will split the input value on whitespace,
// which may not be desirable. If you want to preserve the whole
// value, use set_str_member() instead..
m["attribute2"] = &set_str_member<Something, &Something::attribute2>;

...

Something obj;

std::string value = ...; // "123"
std::string name = ...; // "attribute1"

m[name](obj, value);
/*
Or safer:
std::map<std::string, set_func>::iterator iter = m.find(name);
if (iter != m.end())
    iter->second(obj, value);
*/
```

Comment: Probably cleaner (and definitely faster) to just call `stoi` instead of `istringstream`.  Unless it's really desired to apply locale when reading the settings file.

Comment: You could, if you are using C++11 or later, and don't mind that `stoi()` throws an exception if the conversion fails.

Comment: `strtol` (and `c_str`) being a good option if one really wants to simply ignore errors.